# Prevent screen capture on Windows with C# and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried to prevent screenshots of my WPF window like Microsoft Office.

I tried with SetWindowDisplayAffinity but it always return false and I don't really know where to call this method.

App.xaml:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SetWindowDisplayAffinity(IntPtr hwnd, DisplayAffinity affinity);

protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var mainView = new MainWindow();
    var ok = SetWindowDisplayAffinity(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle, DisplayAffinity.Monitor);
    mainView.Show();
}
```

But the SetWindowDisplayAffinity method always return false. I found another question but it doesn't say where this method should be.

Comment: What do you mean with "like Microsoft Office"? Since when does Microsoft Office prevents you from taking screenshots?

Comment: @elgonzo with IRM/DRM protected files it prevents the screen capture making black the window.

Comment: Doesn't protect from the user just simply pulling out their fondleslab and making a picture of the screen, though.

Comment: @elgonzo that's what i want: https://imgur.com/a/UVyXbP2 It's Microsoft Word but I want the same on my application it works with video recording too

Comment: I don't know how you would do that, unfortunately (Office365 does seem to rely on some DRM-related implementations inside the browser). But looking at this conversation involving some kind of MS representative: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/why-am-i-able-to-capture-the-screenshot-of-a-irm/df2a40ff-6f86-4fff-b0aa-d3dd67dd2598 , even the horse's mouth seems to be of the opinion that it is a fools errand trying to reliably stop someone from making screenshots (in whatever way) once the document is being open and displayed in Office...

Comment: Anyway, if you want to go forward with this, in the answer(s) of this question here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/263112/detect-or-prevent-screen-capture-applications are some suggestions what you could perhaps do. Granted, realizing what is being suggested will be far from trivial and not really bulletproof, but could make it at least a pain in the butt for someone trying to make screenshots...

Comment: With respect to your `SetWindowDisplayAffinity` problem. First suggestion is to call the native `GetLastError` function to see what the actual error was when  `SetWindowDisplayAffinity` returns false. Second suggestion (and speculation on my part), is to try calling `SetWindowDisplayAffinity` after the window is being shown. It could perhaps be that the native main window handle is not being created before the main window is being shown...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an event handler to the Loaded event in the main window: `Loaded="Window_Loaded"`:

Then define that method like the following:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr handle = (new WindowInteropHelper(this)).Handle;
    bool s = SetWindowDisplayAffinity(handle, DisplayAffinity.Monitor);
    MessageBox.Show(s.ToString());
}
```

Then it will return True and that window is blacked out when taking a screenshot.

If you put the same code in the constructor after `InitializeComponent();` then it returns False and the window is not blacked out.

Note that `(new WindowInteropHelper(this)).Handle` will equal `0` if the window is not loaded and it will have a value after it is loaded.