# Is there any way to disable Screen Capture/Screen Recording Flutter win32 app

Tags: flutter, winapi, flutter-windows

I am trying to secure my application, Is there any way of disabling screen capture in win32 application.

Flutter for windows

Thanks in advance
[Output I desire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1m3Kx.png)

Comment: Don't know how you can do that with flutter, but you should use the Windows SetWindowDisplayAffinity https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity API, ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54558151/prevent-screen-capture-on-windows-with-c-sharp-and-wpf

Comment: @SimonMourier Thank you for your help, I was able to achieve the output

Answer (score 3):

I figured out how to disable screen capture in Flutter Windows Application

API Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity

Navigate to Project/windows/runner/main.cpp

Add the below code in wWinMain method:

```
 //DISABLE SCREEN
  HWND code =window.GetHandle();
  SetWindowDisplayAffinity(code, 0x00000011);
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <flutter/dart_project.h>
#include <flutter/flutter_view_controller.h>
#include <windows.h>

#include "flutter_window.h"
#include "utils.h"

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE instance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE prev,
                      _In_ wchar_t *command_line, _In_ int show_command) {
  // Attach to console when present (e.g., 'flutter run') or create a
  // new console when running with a debugger.
  if (!::AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS) && ::IsDebuggerPresent()) {
    CreateAndAttachConsole();
  }

  // Initialize COM, so that it is available for use in the library and/or
  // plugins.
  ::CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);

  flutter::DartProject project(L"data");

  std::vector<std::string> command_line_arguments =
      GetCommandLineArguments();

  project.set_dart_entrypoint_arguments(std::move(command_line_arguments));

  FlutterWindow window(project);
  Win32Window::Point origin(10, 10);
  Win32Window::Size size(1280, 720);
   
  if (!window.CreateAndShow(L"windows_app", origin, size)) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  //DISABLE SCREEN
  HWND code =window.GetHandle();
  SetWindowDisplayAffinity(code, 0x00000011);
  


  window.SetQuitOnClose(true);
  
  ::MSG msg;
  while (::GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) {
    ::TranslateMessage(&msg);
    ::DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }

  ::CoUninitialize();
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```